# File Sorting in HEX on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting

How can I sort file names by HEX instead of whatever Windows 10 does to sort files?
I have a huge list of sound effect files in a folder and because of how Windows has no option (from what I can see) to sort by HEX, I end up having otherwise sorted files show as a complete mess in the folder. I can't find the sound effects I need because the file names are all strange.
There are 9500 files so simply renaming them isn't an option.

Comment: Try this.

Run regedit and go to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

If there's a value called NoStrCmpLogical, set it to 1. If there's no such value, add it as a DWORD with said value.

Comment: You say renaming them isn't an option because there is 9500.  It would be simple to rename them all with a script if that would be preferred?  Can you add to your post a few examples of the file names?  Are they 0x34234, 0x43434, 0x44545, etc..  Do they have an extension, any other text?  A couple of lines of Powershell could rename all the files called 0x423432.ext to 4338738d.ext.  I've added a d at the end to avoid clashes.  Would this sort of thing do?

Comment: Well, some of the files have varying amount of characters in the name.
Since there's so many files it'd be hard to explain, so I apologise if this explanation is a little shaky.

So at the top of the list, I have all of the files that start with 1A as their name, and then it goes 1B, and so on, and then 2A, 2B, ETC. Only after scrolling waaaaay down past all of those do I get the file names that start with two numbers, but it's only those.

Comment: @Nick
I can't do that. After the 'Policies' folder, there's no 'Explorer' folder inside, or anything. The tree completely ends after `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies`.

Comment: Oh and to add on to my previous comment before since I can't edit it for some reason, the files do indeed have a 0x prefix.
It might do, but it depends on if PowerShell reads file names by HEX value and thus would read all of these files in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "NoStrCmpLogical" as DWORD with a value of "1" through regedit DOES work to get Windows Explorer sorting Hex values properly, but it needs to go in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

Not `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

You'll need to restart explorer.exe though the task manager (or just restart the computer) for the change to take effect.

Thanks @Nick for that answer, this has helps me out quite a bit.

Comment: In my system, I have the NoStrCmpLogical value in HKCU and *not* HKLM, and yet it is working as expected for me. It has been working this way on my PC for at least 3 years. I think you might be mistaken in your assertion that it needs to be in HKLM.