# Sorting files and folders by hexadecimal and decimal values

Tags: windows-explorer, sorting, hexadecimal

A while a go I needed to figure out how to sort my files by hexadecimal order. I found some very useful information in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1765437/598567) awesome answer:

> Adding "NoStrCmpLogical" as DWORD with a value of "1" through regedit
> DOES work to get Windows Explorer sorting Hex values properly, but it
> needs to go in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

The result is that my files now sort in hexadecimal order:

[image]

While the file sorting seen in the image above is the expected behavior, I did not expect this to happen with my folders:

[image]

As we can see in the photo above, the order doesn't seem to be displayed in hexadecimal for these folders. I thought perhaps it had something to do with the prefixes before the folder numbers so I tested sorting some directories without the prefixes in their name, but the result was the same:

[image]

So my question is this;

**How can I preserve hexadecimal file sorting for files while also preserving the default display sorting for directories?**

Comment: number the single digit folders as "00", "01" and so on?

Comment: Thank you . If it were only that easy. I am not able to do this. These folders are generated by software that I do not have the code to adapt this sort of change.

Comment: Your two cases are not the same : In the first all numbers have the same number of digits, but in the second they do not. What you see is the correct behavior, because a blank has a lower (hexa)decimal value than a digit, and this can't be changed.

Comment: @harrymc thank you for explaining that.

Comment: You cant have it both ways.  By default, the last image would be sorted correctly.  You have changed it to sort by hex and thats what you are seeing.  How often are these files generated?

Answer (score 1):

Your two cases are not the same : In the first all numbers have the
same number of digits, but in the second they do not.

What you see is the correct behavior, because a blank has a lower
(hexa)decimal value than a digit, and this can't be changed.

If you wish the second case to behave the same as the first one,
you need to take care that all the numbers are of equal length.
Even if the program generating the folders is not under your control,
you may rename the folders later on. If you need to mass-rename,
there are utilities that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revoke [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc)'s accepted answer, but I actually found a solution that will allow me to sort files the way I presented them, and folders the way I had asked about.

To properly display folders that lack a second digit all we need to do is sort them by 'Type' in the Windows File Explorer column:

[image]